# JQuery change function of input field is not defined (shopify cart)

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

In my shopify cart, I have an item input field after each product in the cart. The user can increase or decrease the number of items in cart with this input field. In desktop mode, there is an item increase / decrease button as well, but this is not showing on mobile devices.

The HTML (Liquid Code) of the input field looks like this:

```
<input onblur="this.form.submit();" type="number" class="cart__quantity-selector" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.key }}" value="{{ item.quantity }}" max="{{ item.variant.inventory_quantity }}" min="0" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}">
```

The "max" attribute is limiting the number to the max. available inventory. As customers still can manually exceed the limit by using their keyboard (and not the item increase / decrease buttons) I added a JQuery change function at the bottom of that cart-template.liquid file (that solution I found in another post). This JQuery change function looks like this:

```
<script>
jQuery('[max]').change(function() {
  var max = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('max'), 10) || 10000;
  var value = parseInt(jQuery(this).val(), 10) || 0;
  if (value > max) {
    alert('We only have ' + max + ' items of this product in stock');
    jQuery(this).val(max);
  }
});
</script>
```

This JQuery function was working after implementing, it showed the alert and changed the input field the user was editing to the max. inventory. Now the JQuery function is not firing anymore, I don't know what changed. The console says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

"max" is obviously not defined according to console. By looking at the input element though, 'max' and 'value' is defined properly inside the input field (e.g value = "1" and max = "8"). If anyone has an idea, I'd be very happy.

Comment: In your relevant HTML, are you referencing jQuery? If you are make sure you reference it before your code.

Comment: @BeerusDev Thank you so much for your answer! I was blind! I moved Jquery from <head> to <body>, this made the difference! So JQuery is not yet executed when I try to run the change function. Any idea how to make sure JQuery is executed before the function starts? I really don't want to put the JQuery back in the head, as this issue now seems to be the only problem that appeared so far, and JQuery in <head> s blocking my script and takes loading tinme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to my comment:

`<script>` and `<link>` tags are Elements that can be used inside the `<head>`. In your `<head>` tag, make sure you link the version of jQuery you would like to use, and you can put your function below the body like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input onblur="this.form.submit();" type="number" class="cart__quantity-selector" name="updates[]" id="updates_{{ item.key }}" value="{{ item.quantity }}" max="{{ item.variant.inventory_quantity }}" min="0" aria-label="{{ 'cart.label.quantity' | t }}">

<!-- relevant body html -->

</body>


<script>
jQuery('[max]').change(function() {
  var max = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('max'), 10) || 10000;
  var value = parseInt(jQuery(this).val(), 10) || 0;
  if (value > max) {
    alert('We only have ' + max + ' items of this product in stock');
    jQuery(this).val(max);
  }
});
</script>

</html
```

Relevant articles:

[`<head>`: The Document Metadata (Header) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head)

[The BODY element](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/docbody.html)

Also, side note. IF you do not have any conflicting libraries, you can call jQuery events with `$` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I focused on the following instruction, made by shopify. Under point 2, it says, "What js should be in the head tag?" The answer is "None!" Is that wrong? https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/javascript-performance

Comment: What I do now, as JQuery in the <body> seems to be fine and is speeding up my page a lot due to no blocking, I only execute JQuery in the <head> when it's the cart template. {% if template contains 'cart' %}{{ 'jquery-2.2.3.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}  {% endif %}. I use {% unless template contains 'cart' %}  {{ 'jquery-2.2.3.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}  {% endunless %} in the body to execute JQuery in body if the user is on any other page except cart. You think it's a good solution?

Comment: I would say it is, I would load it at the bottom of your body tag, just make sure it loads before your function

Comment: If this helped, don't forget to upvote :)